# comboBox with checkList

Tags: c#, combobox

How can I do comboBox with checkList in it in C#?

Comment: What platform? And please provide more details on the functionality you are looking for. What have you tried doing so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been messing around with this myself. Here's a small sample of a Control that has real CheckBoxes in it rather than just drawing them. This way you can truly use everything the CheckBox class has to offer. It replaces the regular drop down of the ComboBox with a custom one that inherites ToolStripDropDownMenu which is what allows you to add actual controls to it and solves the problem of the drop down closing whenever you click on an item. You would obviously want to extend the MyComboBox class quite a bit to fit your needs, but it should be a good place to start.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mcb = new MyComboBox() { Left = 6, Top = 6 };
        this.Controls.Add(mcb);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            mcb.AddItem("Item " + i.ToString() );
        }
    }
}

public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private MyDropDown _dropDown;

    public MyComboBox()
    {
        _dropDown = new MyDropDown() { Width = 200, Height = 200 };
    }

    public void AddItem(string text)
    {
        _dropDown.AddControl(new CheckBox() { Text = text });
    }

    public void ShowDropDown()
    {
        if (_dropDown != null)
        {
            _dropDown.Show(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WndUI.WM_REFLECT + WndUI.WM_COMMAND)
        {
            if (WndUI.HIWORD(m.WParam) == WndUI.CBN_DROPDOWN)
            {
                ShowDropDown();
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class MyDropDown : ToolStripDropDownMenu
{
    public MyDropDown()
    {
        this.ShowImageMargin = this.ShowCheckMargin = false;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.Padding = Margin = Padding.Empty;
    }

    public int AddControl(Control control)
    {
        var host = new ToolStripControlHost(control);
        host.Padding = host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        return this.Items.Add(host);
    }

    public void Show(Control control)
    {
        Rectangle area = control.ClientRectangle;
        Point location = control.PointToScreen(new Point(area.Left, area.Top + area.Height));
        location = control.PointToClient(location);
        Show(control, location, ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
        this.Focus();
    }
}

public static class WndUI
{
    public const int
        WM_USER = 0x0400,
        WM_REFLECT = WM_USER + 0x1C00,
        WM_COMMAND = 0x0111,
        CBN_DROPDOWN = 7;

    public static int HIWORD(IntPtr n)
    {
        return HIWORD(unchecked((int)(long)n));
    }

    public static int HIWORD(int n)
    {
        return (n >> 16) & 0xffff;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! do you know how do i make it to stay open so i could check couple of things and then close it?

Comment: Have you tried my code above? The drop-down stays open just like you request. I couldn't figure out how to do it with the normal ComboBox drop-down, so I inherit a ToolStripDropDownMenu to make my own drop-down. The MyComboBox class consumes the Windows Message that tells the normal drop-down to drop, and drops mine instead.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is more suitable I think : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CheckComboBox.aspx

I found this link : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx Hope it helps.

Comment: I able to render a Dropdown with Checkboxes in it. But I need to figure out how can I do a check / uncheck etc.